Yisro wanting to go back to convert people: Moshe says no!
In Parshas Behaaloscha (Bamidbar 10:29), the Torah says:

And Moshe said to Ḥovav, the son of Re῾u᾽el, the Midyanite, Moshe’s father in law, We are journeying to the place of which the L-rd said, I will give it you: come thou with us, and we will do thee good: for the L-rd has spoken good concerning Yisra᾽el.

(side note: the Rabbeinu Bachya explains that Hovav refers to nobody more than Yisro).
The Zayis Raanan (Parshas Behaaloscha, p. 48b), written by the author of the Magen Avraham (Rabbi Abraham Abele Gombiner) explains that Moshe Rabbeinu was saying this as a request:

Here, the word 'na' (please) is used as a form of request. He said to him, 'If you are not coming, then please go with us, for by decree, you are not allowed to leave us.'

Why? The Yalkut Shimoni (ילקוט שמעוני על התורה
תשכ״ו:ז) says:

You may think that you are increasing the honor of Hashem, but you are only diminishing it. How many converts and servants are you destined to bring under the wings of the Divine Presence?

I have trouble understanding why going back to Midian, would diminish the honor of Hashem ? The Satmar Rav in Divrei Yoel (Parshas Chayei Sarah, p. 542) explains that a righteous person always strive to bring other people close to Torah, even sinners.
How to explain all of this according to the opinion of the Zayis Raanan and the Yalkut Shimoni?
Also, the edition on Otzar is not clear and not really readable for me. Can some please provide a clear text/translation of the exact words of the Zayis Raanan? (Bonus :))

Why would Yisro have authority to convert? One can understand if he sought to spread the faith of bnei Noach. But if he traveled with Jews he could bring genuine converts.

@YDJ why not? There is a whole parasha named after him :)

What about Beis Din with 3 judges and 2 witnesses?

@YDJ Yeah okay, but that is not the point to be honest. Please refer to the original question. Avraham, the Rambam says, would tell people about G-d and His Oneness. Maybe that is what Yisro wanted to do in Midian, leading the people to G-d by themselves.

I think the point is this: sure, yisro could go back to midyan and convert some people to Judaism, but by not staying with bnei Yisrael, he'll cause future possible geirim to say "if the father in the law of the king didn't accept Judaism, kal vachomer that we shouldn't/ don't need to" I'm paraphrasing the next part of the yalkut shimoni)
